# Multiple file downloads progress indicators

Tags: javascript, html

So my problem is that i download a multiple file blobs asynchronously and i need a dedicated progress bar for every item, but with this code below script only applies to the last progress bar. Is there any good approach to this? Here is my code:

```
const masterXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  masterXHR.open('GET', res.url, true);
  masterXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${authCookie}`);
  masterXHR.setRequestHeader('X-XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfCookie);
  masterXHR.responseType = 'blob';
  masterXHR.onloadstart = () => { Notifs.downloadNotif(' is downloaded'); };
  masterXHR.onprogress = (e) => {
    const selector = [...document.querySelectorAll('#percentage')];
    const lastIndicator = selector[selector.length - 1];
    lastIndicator.innerText = `${Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100)}%`;
}
  masterXHR.onload = () => { download(masterXHR.response, fileName); };
  masterXHR.send();
```

Fast desc: it searches for every existing `<p>` with id `#percentage` and starts overriding innerText of the last item of nodeList. It also freezes all previous counters, which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs should not have the same names.
Name these id`s as following: percentage1, percentage2, percentage3...